# Merging data.tables at R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have 3 data.tables. They are: A, B, C

I want to merge (join) them by their columns

```
A data.table has AId, Date, ShareId, Quantity
B data.table has Date, Rate
C data.table has Date ShareA, ShareB


    merge(A, B, by="Date")
```

Also, A table's elements are either ShareA or ShareB.

I want to list them like: A.AId, ShareId, Quantity, Rate

Comment: `Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a, b, by="Date", all=TRUE), list(A, B, C))` should work given what we know.

Comment: But can you say why you want to merge in `C` but not retain any of its columns?

Comment: You're not likely to get a whole lot more without a little more substantive example, NewPHPer. Can you please edit your question and include the output from `dput(head(A))` and the same for `B` and `C`, ensuring that the rows you pick (whether with `head` or explicitly) will produce a meaningful merge?